# how many line segments will intersect in a plane will intersect with a horizontal line ? what will be the most effective way to find this

Tags: c++, geometry, combinatorics, line-intersection, line-segment

I’m trying to solve [this Cyberchef challenge](https://www.codechef.com/MARCH20A/problems/LAZER):

> You are given N points in a plane (numbered 1 through N); for each valid i, the i-th point is Pi=(i,Ai). There are N−1 line segments between them (numbered 1 through N−1); for each valid i, the i-th line segment is formed by connecting the points Pi and Pi+1.

You are given Q horizontal line segments . Each query horizontal line segment is denoted by two points, from a point (x1,y) to a point (x2,y) (where it stops and does not propagate further). For Every Horizontal line segment, you have to find the number of line segments from those (N-1 line segments) it collides with on the way.

So this is the problem where:

- 2<=N<= 100000
- 1<=Q<= 100000

Can anyone teach me what approach will be best and most effective in terms of time complexity?

Answer (score 1):

So you have the only polyline and want to check many queries for intersection with horizontal segments.

It is worth to build some kind of binary space partitioning [(BSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) over that polyline. In this case you can check for intersection in `O(log(n))` time, so overall time is `O(nlogn)+O(qlogn)` (building and checking)

---

If yout polyline fortunately is *convex* polygon (without one closing edge), things are quite simpler - just sort edges by Y-coordinate and check only those intersecting query Y (binary search, log(n) per query). In general case (non-convex) your polyline might look like `WMWMWMW` and you have to check too many edges.

Comment: sorry i down't know hwat is polyline or BSP, where ccan i learn in more detail about your approach ?

Comment: Emm... Google and computational geometry books?

Comment: polyline is common term. binary space partitioning - wide class of different data structures.

Answer (score 1):

I used k-d tree to solve this problem. Also dont ask questions that are on-going challenges.

Answer (score 0):

so sweep line algorithm is what you basically need to be aware of, for solving this question.